# Subtract two long functions, possible shortcut using derivative?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $f(x)$ is as follows:

$$f(x)=\frac{2-\ln(x+1)}{x^4 +2}$$

what is $f(a+h)-f(a)$?

I started this problem but quickly realized that the calculations were going to get difficult and long. But I noticed that the desired function is similar to the definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x)= \displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Should I find $f(a+h)-f(a)$ with substitution and traditional operations as I have been doing? Or is there a more direct way to calculate the desired function?

Comment: Once you have taken the limit as $h \to 0$ of that (and got the derivative), you can't "undo" the limit operation and recover an expression for $f(x+h)-f(x).$ [For one thing after taking the limit there is no more $h$ there.]